# Magento 2: cron for custom module

Tags: magento2

I have created new module and create a cron file for it.
I have set cron in system and it is working properly, but my problem is I want to run only my cron file not all.

Code:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/magento-td/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/magento-td/update/cron.php >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento-td/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Comment: Do you want to run  only one custom file through the cron?

Comment: Yes I want to run only my file by cron

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using two files:

create folder and class in root of project like:

**crons/CronprocessApp.php**

```
    <?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

class CronprocessApp
    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface{

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        //$state->setAreaCode('any area'); // or 'adminhtml', depending on your needs
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml'); // or 'adminhtml', depending on your needs
    }
    public function launch()
    {
        /** @var \Vendor\Module\Cron\Test $cron */
        $cron = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create('Custom\Preorder\Cron\ChangeVisiblityNonPreorderProduct'); //pass the name of your cron class path 
        $cron->execute();       


        return $this->_response;

    }
    public function catchException(\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Create another class file:

**crons/Cronprocess.php**

```
 <?php
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../crons/cronprocessApp.php';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CronprocessApp');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

To Run cron go to cli with project root path and run below command:

```
php crons/cronprocess.php
```

Comment: I am not getting what you say

Comment: You want to run only you cron right?

Comment: Yes I just want to run my cron file

Comment: Okay then go to Project root and create folder called "crons" and create two above files inside that folder and pass your cron folder path in this file: CronprocessApp.php and To run cron go to CLI with project root directory and run this command: php crons/cronprocess.php

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php yourcustomfilepath/index.php
```

in index.php file just put your logic that you want to run in cron.

====================================================================

There is also another way to run your custom file during the default Magento cron is run.
creates the `etc/crontab.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="cron_feed" instance="VendorName\CompanyName\Model\CustomFile" method="getfile"> //you can creates file in Controller or Helper also
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Create the class for your logic :

```
<?php 
namespace VendorName\CompanyName\Model;


class CustomFile extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    public function getfile()
    {
        // write your logic here
    }
}
```

One thing, this cron executed when your default magento cron will executed.So you need to set below one cron for magento.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /var/www/html/magento-td/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> var/www/html/magento-td/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Comment: I have added this code in system cron, now need to run any command? I have added this line, but nothing is runnig

Comment: system cron? Sorry I didn't get you.
run crontab -e and setup this cron
===>
* * * * * /usr/bin/php yourcustomfilepath/customfile.php
In customfile.php write your logic that you want to run in cron.

Comment: I do this but after 15 minutes I get no entry in cron table.

Comment: This trick is for just a logic that you want to perform in cron.It will not add entry in cron table.

Comment: I mean, when cron executed by this code,  magento will add one entry in `cron_schedule` for this cron.

Comment: Entry in cron_schedule table is added is when Magento cron is not executed. I mean cron is an schedule not executed yet that Kind of entries in  cron_schedule table.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check that.Hope it will help you.

Comment: I did this but it will run all crons

Comment: Then you have to go with this
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php yourcustomfilepath/customfile.php
It will not run all crons just run your custom file customfile.php
also it will not add any entry in cron_schedule, because it's not magento cron so.